# How to manage IPv6 addresses when you have < 1MB RAM?

Tags: embedded, ipv6

I want to implement IPv6 in a small appliance that has less than 1MB RAM.

I have read that a NIC can have a lot of IPv6 addresses.

It looks like having 3 addresses is the bare minimum (one link local address, one global address and one ULA.)

How many addresses are reasonable to allocate being on a memory constrained device?

Keep in mind that we are talking of an appliance and not a generic computer that can host a VM.

UPDATE:
The IPv6 stack is already done, I'm able to communicate with a link-local address. My question is now about the number of addresses that I need to manage. As a first step, I'm specifically interested on "how many I need to store in non-volatile memory?" (it is an always-on appliance but you know). In terms of IPv6 services, there can be a web server, a cloud connection (client) and a bus "server".

Also, by appliance, I mean a "home appliance".

Comment: By "appliance" do you mean "household appliance", e.g. connected refrigerator or "computer appliance", e.g. router?

Comment: more like a household appliance

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by managing IPv6 addresses? An IPv6 address is 16 bytes each. You can store 65536 IPv6 addresses into a megabyte. How many IPv6 addresses do you think you need to manage, and in what way exactly?

Comment: It was not really clear, sorry. 1MB is for the whole system, the less I have to allocate to IPv6 addresses, the better.

Comment: Yes, but you did not say how many you need to manage, what does managing them mean, and what is the problem? How many IPv6 addresses do you need for a simple appliance, and why?

Comment: How many I need to manage is my question. When I say "manage" I mean : create, read, update and delete. As a first step, I'm specifically interested on "how many I need to store in non-volatile memory?" (it is an always-on appliance but you know). In terms of IPv6 services, there can be a web server, a cloud connection and a bus "server".

Comment: I'm no network expert (which, you might want to ask on StackOverflow or etc.), but it sounds like you will simply have three (web server, cloud server, bus server), or maybe multiples of each. What other IPs were you expecting? If you don't know, perhaps rephrase the question as "am I missing something, will this be just this simple?", what have others needed in similar kinds of projects, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

A router, switch or similar device that *manages* IP addresses for other devices and for sending information to various networks will benefit from having a large storage of addresses. But no (or almost no - somebody will build a *huge* device just to prove me wrong) device will actually handle every possible address *in memory*. You have a set amount of memory for IP addresses (or for routing in general - just storing the address doesn't mean much, you need to keep track of what to do with packets being sent to that address) and when that memory gets full you dump the oldest information to make room for new information.

But all of that should be irrelevant with an appliance - or any ordinary computer. A simple device (by which I mean, anything that isn't *managing* network traffic for other devices) needs to have a network stack - a bunch of software that lets a computer to talk to other things on the network. This can support IPv4, IPv6 or both. This software, plus whatever else you need on the device, could take a little RAM or a **lot**. For example, [this article about embedded systems (and appliances are a good example of embedded systems)](https://www.embedded.com/ipv6-on-a-microcontroller/) says some embedded systems *with IPv6** can run with as little as 128K of RAM. So a 1 MB system is quite plausible. The devil is in the details.

Comment: The IPv6 stack is already done, I'm able to communicate with a link-local address. My question is now about the number of addresses that I need to manage. As a first step, I'm specifically interested on "how many I need to store in non-volatile memory?" (it is an always-on appliance but you know). In terms of IPv6 services, there can be a web server, a cloud connection (client) and a bus "server".

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check and see how much resources a basic IPv6 stack consumes. The best way to do this is to get a copy for the compiler you are using and see how much memory resources it needs. You can cut down on the buffer size and other things.

Its also noteworthy that minimum IPv6 packets are a little more than double the size of IPv4 packets.

> Both protocols have a minimum MTU requirement. This is 576 bytes for
> IPv4 and 1280 bytes for IPv6.

Source: [Electronic Design](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/embedded-revolution/article/21802146/whats-the-difference-between-ipv4-and-ipv6)

Comment: The IPv6 stack is already done, I'm able to communicate with a link-local address. My question is now about the number of addresses that I need to manage.